# Is it possible to get a TON of data with springboot or should we try something else?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heap-memory, jdbctemplate

I am running into a problem where I run out of memory trying to use a select query on a table with 232 million records. The specific field is a String with 17 characters. I am basically tasked with making a connection to a specific table get the selected data then use that data to call an API. Then ingest that to another table. I am, of course, running out of memory. Does anyone have any suggestions. I am keeping it general since I cannot share the codebase, but I am wondering if this design should work with such a large dataset.

below is my runner.

```
 @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        final long startTimeAt = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // List with all the data from AT database
        List<Data> data = DataRepository.getData(); //ERROR
        final long endTimeAt = System.currentTimeMillis();

        log.info("AT data retrieval took time: {}", endTimeAt - startTimeAt);
```

This is how I am getting data

```
@Override
    public List<Data> getData() {
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(10000);
        return jdbcTemplate.query(getVinDataQuery, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Data.class));
    }
```

If it helps here is the error I am getting:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Have you tried increasing the heap size?

Comment: Or getting the data in chunks instead of all of them at the same time?

Comment: Yeah @FedericoklezCulloca , that was the first thing I tried. I increased it to 6GBs and still running out of memory.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca could you explain what you mean by getting the data in chunks?

Comment: you can certainly share a similar coding example.

Comment: Or you could use a key or some other `WHERE` filter to get _less_ data.

Comment: I mean, even if you can load 6GB of records into memory, what are you going to do with them? You say you have to use this data to fetch some related data from an API, are you expecting to send 6GB to an API?

Comment: @user229044 I get the data then call the API one at a time in a for loop then once the data is retrieved from the API I ingest to the DataSource.

Comment: Are you doing that 272 million times? Or are you filtering down the data set and making dramatically fewer requests? Can you move that filtering into the database via a `where`?

Comment: @user229044 I am not filtering the data down. I planned on calling the API that many times. I was tasked with getting all that data and the returned json in its own location in a new table. I might look more but I do not think I can filter using a ```WHERE```.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to load full dataset into memory, but instead you should process it on-the-fly:

```
class JdbcTemplate {
    public void query(String sql, RowCallbackHandler rch) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

E.g.:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(getVinDataQuery, rs -> {
    // process each row...
    final String id = rs.getString("id");
    final String text = rs.getString("text");

    doProcessRow(new Data(id, text));
});
```